# Is there a way to manage snowflake default roles like Accountadmin via Scim Api calls

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, scim

Is there a way to manage snowflake default roles like Accountadmin via Scim Api calls.
I want a user to get Accountadmin role in snowflake when its added to the corresponding group in Active Directory. I know that in order to create a group-user association using Scim call, I need the snowflake group ID for that particular group. In this case, the group is Accountadmin and I don't think there is a way to get the group ID for the same. Even if I get the group ID, the Scim calls won't work because Accountadmin is not owned by the Generic_Scim_Provisioner role.

Note: I am using custom SCIM integration to sync snowflake with the Active Directory. All the roles and users created in snowflake are owned and managed by Generic_Scim_Provisioner role, as suggested here:
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/scim-custom.html

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom role called `SCIM_ACCOUNTADMIN` or something along those lines, grant `ACCOUNTADMIN` to that role, and then use the group ID of `SCIM_ACCOUNTADMIN` for the SCIM integration.  It's a bit of a workaround, but should work pretty nicely.

Answer (score 0):

you have to create the accountadmin group in AD as SCIM in AD mapped groups to role in Snowflake, so any users assigned to the group gets provisioned in snowflake and with default accountadmin role.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have Accountadmin role Synched with SCIM then I am afraid that this is not possible.
In order for the provisioning to work the object needs to be owned for the provisioned role which you create(AAD_PROVISIONER, OKTA_PROVISIONER etc).

Even if you create a group on your SCIM provider with the ACCOUNTADMIN and try to sync as it will fail because the ACCOUNTADMIN role is not owned by the provisioner role and it cannot be changed.

You can however try the following.

Create a Group on SCIM provider with names like ACCOUNTADMIN_AAD, or ACCOUNTADMIN_CUSTOM, or any other role you like.

Once Synched you will see the Role which you created above.
Execute the command:
Grant role ACCOUNTADMIN to role ;

This way when users who are part of the GROUP in the SCIM provider will be granted to ROLE which you created earlier, and as this is granted with ACCOUNTADMIN role these users will have accountadmin role granted to them.